# Google cloud storage versioned bucket not obeying lifecycle rule

Tags: google-cloud-storage, versioning, lifecycle

I would like to have a maximum of only 2 versions of all objects in my google cloud storage bucket. I have enabled object versioning and have added a lifecycle rule to delete any objects with more than 2 versions. I then start adding objects multiple times to the bucket and run

```
 gsutil ls -R -a gs://bucketname
```

I end up seeing 3 or 4 different generations of each object even after several minutes of waiting they are not deleted.

Eg:

```
gs://bucketname/b331108b.csv.gz#1562856078193350
gs://bucketname/b331108b.csv.gz#1564856078195342
gs://bucketname/b331108b.csv.gz#1565856078143350
gs://bucketname/b331108b.csv.gz#1567856078193551
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Updates to your lifecycle configuration may take up to 24 hours to go into effect. This means that when you change your lifecycle configuration, Object Lifecycle Management may still perform actions based on the old configuration for up to 24 hours.

Comment: @Kolban ok I'll wait a day and check. thanks

Comment: @Kolban I gave it a few days just to be sure - it seems older versions still remain even after days of changing the lifecycle configuration.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of:  gsutil lifecycle get gs://[BUCKET_NAME]

Comment: I have same problem... `{"rule": [{"action": {"storageClass": "NEARLINE", "type": "SetStorageClass"}, "condition": {"numNewerVersions": 2}}, {"action": {"type": "Delete"}, "condition": {"numNewerVersions": 3}}]}`
Objects not moving or deleting.